# how to get the Default Listview Value in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application i have customListView ,i need to get the first value of list view(i.e. Zero position value) when very first time activity is loaded without using OnItemClickLiseners and it is focusable.How Can i do?,please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: ,i need to get the first value of list view. means ?

Comment: zero position value of the listview

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
   listView.getChildAt(0)
```

or

```
   listView.getChildAt(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is based on the assumption that you need to pull out values of the item that is at the first (0th) position in the `ListView`.*

Since you are using a Custom `ListView`, you should also have a custom `Adapter` (possibly an `ArrayAdapter` or a `BaseAdapter`) that you use to show the data etc.

In any case, just check for this in the `getView()`:

```
if (position == 0) {
    // GET WHAT EVER DATA YOU NEED OUT OF THE ITEM.
}
```

If you can add more info to the OP about how you deal with the data, perhaps this answer can be made a little bit more useful. For example, do you use a POJO class to bind the data to the `ListView`?

Comment: Thanks,it worked for me and how to set it as selectable mode.